# Is it possible to do conditional formatting on an org-table?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table, javascript

Here is an example of a table to format,

- the first row represents how often a task is done per year,
- the first column represents how long a task takes in seconds

```
|-------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------|
|       |      18250 |      1825 |      365 |      52 |      12 |     1 |
|-------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------|
|     1 |      18250 |      1825 |      365 |      52 |      12 |     1 |
|     5 |      91250 |      9125 |     1825 |     260 |      60 |     5 |
|    30 |     547500 |     54750 |    10950 |    1560 |     360 |    30 |
|    60 |    1095000 |    109500 |    21900 |    3120 |     720 |    60 |
|   300 |    5475000 |    547500 |   109500 |   15600 |    3600 |   300 |
|  1800 |   32850000 |   3285000 |   657000 |   93600 |   21600 |  1800 |
|  3600 |   65700000 |   6570000 |  1314000 |  187200 |   43200 |  3600 |
| 21600 |  394200000 |  39420000 |  7884000 | 1123200 |  259200 | 21600 |
| 86400 | 1576800000 | 157680000 | 31536000 | 4492800 | 1036800 | 86400 |
|-------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------|
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*@1$2::$3=$1*@1$3::$4=$1*@1$4::$5=$1*@1$5::$6=$1*@1$6::$7=$1*@1$7
```

Is it possible to change the cell display while keeping the values?

Here are some examples of displays:

```
|-------+-------+---------|
| Cell  | Value | Display |
|-------+-------+---------|
| @1$4  |   365 | Daily   |
| @1$7  |     1 | Yearly  |
| @3$6  |    60 | 1 m     |
| @6$6  |  3600 | 1 h     |
| @10$1 | 86400 | 1 d     |
|-------+-------+---------|
```

Here is a complete example from https://xkcd.com (where values are multiplied by 5):

[image: XKCD chart]

Ideally, I would like the display to be generated according to some rules (e.g. for all rows below row 1, if  3600 < x > 59, divide by 60 and add " m"), and to show a heat map.

I don't necessarily need the formatting to be done by org-mode. The table will be exported to HTML, so ideally, the formatting would be done through HTML export and JS code (using some cdn library).

Comment: As the question is mainly about JS, maybe I should post the question to StackOverflow instead. If this is the case, please tell me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT **The easiest (best?) solution is in the 'list of lists' part at the end of this answer**

In principle this would be best achieved using the `org-export-before-processing-hook`, as you could replace contents directly instead of modifying the html code. However, I am not aware of any function that would directly provide you the 'cell address' in that case.

Because such 'address' function is available for the export filters, we use a filter here.
So in this case you can use the somewhat hidden function `org-export-table-cell-address` in `ox.el` to obtain a cell's row and column (index starting from 0). For getting the number values, you can use `org-element-contents`. The following example shows how you could achieve what you ask for:

```lisp
(defun my-cell-export-filter-fn (data backend info)
  (let* ((cell (seq-some (lambda (tp)
                         (plist-get (caddr tp) :parent))
                         (object-intervals data)))
         (address (org-export-table-cell-address cell info)))
    (when cell
      ;; (print (org-export-table-cell-address cell info))
      ;; (print (substring-no-properties data))
      (let ((contents (car (org-element-contents cell))))
        (if (= (car address) 0)
            (setq data (string-replace contents (pcase contents
                                                  ("365" "Daily")
                                                  ("52" "Weekly")
                                                  ("12" "Monthy")
                                                  ("52" "Yearly")
                                                  (t contents))
                                       data))
          (setq data (pcase address
                       ((or '(6 . 1) '(7 . 1) '(8 . 1)
                            '(9 . 1) '(8 . 2) '(9 . 2)
                            '(8 . 3) '(9 . 3) '(9 . 4))
                        (string-replace "<td" "<td style=\"background-color:red;color:black;\" " data))
                       (_ data)))
          (let ((value (string-to-number contents)))
            (when (< 59 value 3600)
              ;; (print value)
              ;; (print (substring-no-properties data))
              (setq value (/ value 60.0)
                    data (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:digit:]]+" (format "%.1fm" value) data))))))))
  data)

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-table-cell-functions #'my-cell-export-filter-fn)
```

Evaluate the code, and export your org file to html. You should see the modified table when viewing the html file in a browser.

To see the original html format of the cells you can uncomment the commented lines.

**org-export-before-processing-hook solution example:**

Although it might be redundant, as I have the code anyway, I'll include a code example for a solution when using the `org-export-before-processing-hook`, where we have to implement our own tricks to determine the cell address

```lisp
(defun format-table-fn (backend)
  (let ((rows 0)
        (cells 0)
        cols)
    (when (eq backend 'html)
      ;; first we determine the number of rows and columns
      (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'table
        (lambda (table)
          (when (string= (org-element-property :name table) "efficiency-table")
                  (org-element-map table 'table-row
                    (lambda (row)
                      (let ((n (length (org-element-map row 'table-cell #'identity))))
                        (when (> n 0)
                          (cl-incf cells n)
                          (cl-incf rows))))))))
      (setq cols (/ cells rows))
      ;; now we can use the table dimensions to 'account for cell address'
      (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'table
        (lambda (table)
          (when (string= (org-element-property :name table) "efficiency-table")
            (let ((row 1)
                  (col 1))
              (org-element-map table 'table-cell
                (lambda (cell)
                  (pcase (cons row col)
                    ('(1 . 3) (let ((beg (org-element-property :contents-begin cell))
                                    (end (org-element-property :contents-end cell)))
                                (replace-region-contents beg end (lambda () "Daily")))))
                  (if (= (% col cols) 0)
                      (setq col 1)
                    (cl-incf col))
                  (if (= (% row rows) 0)
                      (setq row 1)
                    (cl-incf row)))))))))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-functions #'format-table-fn)
```

**list of lists**

The easiest solution is to parse the table to a list of lists first.

Actually, this happens automatically when passing a table as a variable to another src-block. Unfortunately, the text-properties (i.e. the face) do not get included in the formatted table, but we can still use emphasis markers to change the formatting. You can then additonaly configure `org-emphasis-alist` to configure the formatting in org, and `org-html-text-markup-alist` e.g. using:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-html-text-markup-alist  '(strike-through . "<font color=\"red\">%s</font>"))
```

to configure the formatting on html export.

(to use the below code block, name your table 'efficiency-table')

```lisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var tbl=efficiency-table :exports result
(seq-map-indexed (lambda (e i)
           (if (= i 0)
               (mapcar (lambda (label)
                 (pcase label
                   (365 "Daily")
                   (52 "Weekly")
                   (12 "Monthly")
                   (1 "Yearly")
                   (_ label)))
                   e)
             (seq-map-indexed (lambda (f j)
                    (when (< 59 f 3600)
                      (setq f (format "%.1fm" (/ (round (/ f 60.0) 0.1) 10.0))))
                    (pcase (cons i j)
                      ((or '(6 . 1) '(7 . 1) '(8 . 1)
                           '(9 . 1) '(8 . 2) '(9 . 2)
                           '(8 . 3) '(9 . 3) '(9 . 4))
                       ;; unfortunately the face
                       ;; does not get included in
                       ;; the resulting table

                       ;; (propertize (number-to-string f) 'help-echo "HOI"))
                       (format "+%d+" f))
                      (_ f)))
                      e)))
         tbl)
#+end_src
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly for formatting one cell at a time. But can we format several cells at once? For example, apply `(string-replace "<td" "<td style=\"background-color:grey;color:grey;\" " data)` to cells (6 . 1),(7 . 1), (8.1), (9.1), (8.2), (9.2), (8.3), (9.3), (9.4). Or apply rules based on values (e.g. for all rows below row 1, if 3600 < x > 59, divide by 60 and add " m")? I was not able to find much documentation on `org-export-table-cell-address`...

Comment: The `org-export-table-cell-address` is just to get the row and column numbers (you can wrap it in a print, to see its return value). You can print the contents of the cells by commenting out the lines. Then you can use the `pcase` to select the cells you mentioned (read about `pcase` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/pcase-Macro.html)). Or you could replace the `pcase` with a `when` or `cond` for applying rules based on values.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hints. I don't know much about Elisp, but I'll try to find out the solution from there. I'll post the solution here when I find it.

Comment: To use conditions by value, you can use `org-element-contents`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much your solution works quite well and is very instructive. I don't think I would have managed to achieve that by myself. I thought of another possible way but I don't know if it is possible. The idea is to have two tables. The original one, under a commented headline, and a second one (which would be exported) generated from the original one. Is it possible to generate an org-table by extracting and transforming elements from another one?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your question, but I think the 'list of lists' section of my answer might answer it. You should name your original table and then pass it as a variable to an org src-block. The table will be 'parsed' to a list of lists, which you can transform to create your new table. The only problem with that solution is that I don't know how to apply a 'face' to (parts of) the table. (Try it... name your table as instructed and then copy and evaluate that example src-block)

Comment: Yes, the 3d solution you provided answered the question indeed. Sorry for not having understood enough your 3 solutions :/ By the way, in this solution, it's only when I remove `results :results raw` from the first line that I can see a table in the results.

Comment: And yes, this solution is the best. I think the color issue can be solved by just removing the values, so these cells are shown as blanks.

Comment: Ah cool! Yeah, the `:results raw` was a copy-paste mistake. I used it to see if the text-properties (the face) got applied/included.

Comment: I have added a nice suggestion, namely to format the cells using emphasis markers. This also works nicely on html export.